# How to join more than one table rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've got a bit of code that I'm looking at the moment :

```
User.includes([:profile => :schedule]).where('...')
```

This loads all profiles and their schedules. So the query produced by this is select * user fields, select * profile fields, select * schedule fields

I'm filtering out users based on one field from profile and based on one field from profiles schedule but this above statement is selecting all the fields from all of these.

So I tried to do it with joins :

```
User.joins(:profile).joins('profiles.schedule').where('....').select('....')
```

This is throwing out error. I'm a former Java developer, still learning the rails stuff.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
User.joins(profile: :schedule).where('....').select('....')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.joins(profile: [:schedule]).where('...')
```

or

```
User.joins(profile: :schedule).where('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've set your `Profile` model to have the association `Schedule` using the [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association then you can just use this:

```
User.joins(:schedule).where('...')
```